# Juego con intentos infinitos

Tags: python

Buenas soy nuevo en python tengo una tarea que hacer, se me pide hacer con dos clases el juego de adivinar un número con intentos infinitos se pide por teclado el numero de intentos infinitos mi duda es ¿como puedo hacerlo con dos clases? el primer ejercicio si que me ha salido pero no se como hacer el segundo, mas que nada por la segunda clase. Con una sola clase lo se hacer y también mostrar los intentos que han sido con una lista.

Os muestro el codigo del primer ejercicio, si alguien me puede ayudar estaría muy agradecido.

Gracias :)

```
import random

class Juego_Avidinar():

    def __init__(self):
        self.minimo = 1
        self.maximo = 100

    def genera_numero_aleatorio(self):
        return random.randint(self.minimo, self.maximo)


    def empieza_juego(self):
        numero_random = self.genera_numero_aleatorio()
        print(numero_random)

        print(
            f"Adivina el número generado aleatoriamente {self.minimo} y {self.maximo}")

        while True:
            numero_usuario = int(input("Introduzca el número: "))
            if numero_usuario == numero_random:
                print(
                    f"-> Enhorabuena ha adivinado el número!!!")
                break
            elif numero_usuario < numero_random:
                print("-> El número introducido es menor que el número aleatorio")
            else:
                print("-> El número introducido es mayor que el número aleatorio")

Juego_Avidinar = Juego_Avidinar()
Juego_Avidinar.empieza_juego()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Podrias definir una clase Reglas que representa las reglas del juego

   - Rango de numeros (minimo y maximo)
   - Genera un numero aleatorio entre esos valores.
   - Numero de intentos
2. Defines la clase Juego a la cual le pasas un objeto Reglas y se encarga de

   - Mensajes para el jugador y condiciones de terminacion

Ejemplo:

```
    import random

    class Reglas():
        
        def __init__(self, rango=(0,100), intentos=5):
            self.min = rango[0]
            self.max = rango[1]
            self.intentos = intentos
            self.numero = random.randint(self.minimo, self.maximo)
            self.revisar_reglas()

        def revisar_reglas(self):
            assert self.max > self.min
            assert self.intentos > 0

    
    class Juego():

        def __init__(self, reglas):
            self.reglas = reglas

        def empezar_juego(self):
            while self.reglas.intentos > 0:
                print(f'Adivina el numero entre {self.reglas.min} y {self.reglas.max}'
                numero_usuario = int(input("Introduzca el numero..."))
                ..."y ya pues pones el resto de codigo"



    reglas = Reglas(rango=(20,40), intentos=2)
    juego = Juego(reglas)
    juego.empezar_juego()

    reglas = Reglas(intentos=10)
    juego = Juego(reglas)
    juego.empezar_juego()
```